# Using > in prometheus query

Tags: prometheus

Using this query in Prometheus throws error. Please let me know how to check this condition.

Query: `asm_disk{percent_utilized >= 30}`

```
asm_disk{exported_job="asm_disk_status", free_mb="2431500", group_number="3", instance="pr14xg-as-4p.cable.comcast.com:9091", itrc_env="production", job="pushgateway", percent_utilized="53.44094669117647", total_mb="5222400"} 1

asm_disk{exported_job="asm_disk_status", free_mb="30500", group_number="4", instance="pr14xg-as-4p.cable.comcast.com:9091", itrc_env="production", job="pushgateway", percent_utilized="40.4296875", total_mb="51200"} 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) for labels.

One can do such a comparison only using  regex matching for labels (operators `=~`, `!~`).

---

On the other hand, I would argue, you should rethink your metrics completely. Labels are wrong place to store decimal values.

Create two separate metrics: for total space and free space per device:

```
asm_disk_free_space_bytes{exported_job="asm_disk_status", free_mb="", group_number="3", instance="pr14xg-as-4p.cable.comcast.com:9091", itrc_env="production", job="pushgateway"} 2431500000000

asm_disk_total_space_bytes{exported_job="asm_disk_status", group_number="3", instance="pr14xg-as-4p.cable.comcast.com:9091", itrc_env="production", job="pushgateway"} 5222400000000
```

Utilization in this case can be calculated as

```
1 - asm_disk_free_space_bytes / asm_disk_total_space_bytes
# or if you want percents:
100 - asm_disk_free_space_bytes / asm_disk_total_space_bytes * 100
```

Comment: You would argue correctly; metrics (not labels) should be used to store measurements (of values) such as `free_mb`, `total_mb`, and `percent_utilized`

Comment: @DazWilkin, is there a canonical answer somewhere for this? I'm pretty sure it should exist, but I've failed to find one.

Comment: A good question. It gets treated as assumed and it really shouldn't be. A good source for this may Google's SRE content; I'll have a browse.

Comment: I've been unable to find a good, concise definition. For me, it's something of the form: if I need (not just like) to measure something, it's a metric. If I need to disambiguate measurements from distinct sources, I use labels. In Kubernetes, resources labels are generally more useful than resource names and workloads are more useful (e.g. Deployments are more useful than Pods).

Comment: @DazWilkin, this rule of thumb I understand.  I meant a canonical answer at SO, to link duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps your answer should become it?